Chrome or Firefox extension to share sessions between computers (share e.g. cookies and localStorage)
I switch way too often between a number of computers (2 OSes on my laptop, my desktop, my parents' computer, my work laptop) and I'd like them all to share their sessions:

I wish to share the login cookies on the various websites.
I wish to share my preferences on the various websites
I wish to share my progress on games on itch.io and similar websites.
And so on and so forth.

How can I achieve that? Are there any working extension which offer that?
I know about Sync-my-cookie, but it's no longer maintained and it's not compatible with the latest chrome.

I understand the games and preferences part, but login cookies should really not be shared due to security
